# PHP don't show double outputs

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, unique

I'm getting data out of my database with a query that selects Klantvraag numbers.

The output at the moment shows 5x the same output Klantvraag number.
The problem there is that those 5 numbers each have same address but different house numbers.

So basically if there are 5 Klantvraag numbers I want it to only select the number once and output it once in a selectbox.

Can you help me with that ?

```
<?php 
    include("config/instellingen.php");
    $query = "SELECT Klantvraag FROM `DWA` WHERE `Status DWA` = 'DBAA' AND `Kenmerk` > ''";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
        while ($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<option value="' . $get['Klantvraag'] . '">' . $get['Klantvraag'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Klantvraag FROM `DWA` WHERE `Status DWA` = 'DBAA' AND `Kenmerk` > ''";
```

This will only add any occuring value once to your result.

Comment: Thanks, and what a fast reply awesome!

Answer (score 0):

use DISTINCT keyword and the query will be

SELECT DISTINCT Klantvraag FROM `DWA` WHERE Status DWA = 'DBAA' AND `Kenmerk` > ''
Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` and query something like this

```
$query = "SELECT Klantvraag FROM `DWA` WHERE `Status DWA` = 'DBAA' AND `Kenmerk` > '' group by `Klantvraag`";
```